# SharpPcap SendQueue does not work as in the example

Tags: c#

i try to send packets from pcap file (libpcap) using SharpPcap and using the example from SharpPcap: http://sourceforge.net/p/sharppcap/code/ci/SharpPcap_4_1_0/tree/Examples/Example10.SendQueue/Example10.SendQueues.cs

my problem is in line 127 - `int sent = winPcapDevice.SendQueue(squeue, SharpPcap.WinPcap.SendQueueTransmitModes.Synchronized);` and when try to execute this command i get exception that **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
i have checked line by line with the debugger and it seems that everything works fine until this command, my `Pcap` file OK, all the packets is placed inside the `Queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the debugger the value of winPcapDevice. If it's null, then this is your problem. Otherwise please post the stack trace, it is possible that the exception is thrown from inside of `SendQueue`.

To find out why winPcapDevice appears null, track in the debugger the life time of the instance you are expecting to end up in this variable: the `device` variable and then the `devices` array. Examine what are inside those as you step through the code.

If `device` is not null but running the following line of code:

```
var winPcapDevice = device as WinPcapDevice;
```

results in `winPcapDevice` being null it means that the instance that `device` is holding cannot be cast to `WinPcapDevice` type. Basically it's of a different type that also does not inherit from `WinPcapDevice` Refer to [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the explanation how 'as' operator works.

Comment: @user2214609 I've added to the answer

Comment: my problem is in this line: var winPcapDevice = device as WinPcapDevice;, device not null but var is null

Comment: @user2214609 then the type is not expected one. Refer to the link below for the explanation how 'as' operator works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i think it should be type WinPcapDevice because the SendQueue method who refer to this type